# Problem with Massey's exercise 3.3

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm stuck with the following problem from Massey's book:

"If $f,g$ are paths over $X$ with initial point $x_0$ and terminal point $x_1$ prove that $f$ is equivalent to $g$ iff $f\cdot \bar{g}$ is equivalent to the constant path $x_0$"

where $\bar{g}$ denotes the path $\bar{g}(t)=g(1-t)$.

If anyone could help me I would be more than gratefull.

Comment: Could you tell us the work you have done on the problem so far? And which Massey book do you mean? Amazon.com has $497$ hits for "Massey" under the Science and Math category of books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is equivalent to $g$, then $f\cdot \bar{g}$ is equivalent to $g\cdot \bar{g}$. Since $g\cdot \bar{g}$ is equivalent to the constant path at $x_0$, so is $f\cdot \bar{g}$ equivalent to the constant path at $x_0$.

Conversely, if $f\cdot \bar{g}$ is equivalent to the constant path at $x_0$, then $f\cdot \bar{g}\cdot g$ is equivalent to $ c_{x_0}\cdot g$ (I'm using $c_{x_0}$ to denote the constant path at $x_0$). Since $\bar{g}\cdot g$ and $ c_{x_0}\cdot g$ are equivalent to $c_{x_0}$ and $g$, respectively, then $f$ is equivalent to $g$.